# How to access Controls in WPF Frame navigation bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I added a StackPanel to Frame's Navigation bar.
I right clicked on my frame, then Edit Template and Edit Current, then I've added my named StackPanel and some buttons right next to navigation buttons. Great! It worked.

```
<Frame  x:Name="MainContent" Content="{Binding CurrentContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" Style="{DynamicResource FrameStyle1}">
                    <Frame.Resources>
                        <!-- Something -->
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameNavChromeTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationChromeBackground}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="22">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Menu x:Name="NavMenu" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="16" Margin="1,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowMenu}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <MenuItem ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NavigationWindowNavigationButtonJournalEntryStyle}" Padding="0,2,4,0" Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowMenuItem}">
                                                <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource JournalEntryUnifiedViewConverter}">
                                                        <Binding Path="BackStack" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="ForwardStack" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                                            </MenuItem>
                                        </Menu>
                                        <Path Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Data="M22.5767,21.035 Q27,19.37 31.424,21.035 A12.5,12.5,0,0,0,53.5,13 A12.5,12.5,0,0,0,37.765,0.926 Q27,4.93 16.235,0.926 A12.5,12.5,0,0,0,0.5,13 A12.5,12.5,0,0,0,22.5767,21.035 z" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="2,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Path.Fill>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#A0C2CCE7" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Path.Fill>
                                            <Path.LayoutTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.667" ScaleX="0.667"/>
                                            </Path.LayoutTransform>
                                            <Path.Stroke>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFB7C2E3" Offset="0.2"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#A0FFFFFF" Offset="0.9"/>
                                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Path.Stroke>
                                        </Path>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="0" Margin="3,0,1,0" Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowBackButtonStyle}">
                                            <Button.LayoutTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.667" ScaleX="0.667"/>
                                            </Button.LayoutTransform>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="1,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle}">
                                            <Button.LayoutTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.667" ScaleX="0.667"/>
                                            </Button.LayoutTransform>
                                        </Button>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="CUSTOMNAVBAR" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,0,10,0">
                                            <Button></Button>
                                            <Button></Button>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_FrameCP"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="CanGoForward" Value="false"/>
                                        <Condition Property="CanGoBack" Value="false"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" TargetName="NavMenu" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <!-- Something -->

 </Frame.Resources>
                </Frame>
```

But I have no clue how to access this panel.. I have tried:

```
        var x = (StackPanel)MainContent.Template.FindName("CUSTOMNAVBAR", MainContent);
        var y = (StackPanel)FindName("CUSTOMNAVBAR");
        var k = (StackPanel)MainContent.FindResource("CUSTOMNAVBAR");
        var i = (StackPanel)MainContent.Resources.FindName("CUSTOMNAVBAR");
        var z = (StackPanel)FindResource("CUSTOMNAVBAR");
```

And it keeps returning null or throwing an exception... Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var x = (StackPanel)MainContent.Template.FindName("CUSTOMNAVBAR", MainContent);
```

But be sure that you run the code when the Window has ***already been loaded*** such as by putting the code in some `Loaded` event handler. Or you can also try calling `ApplyTemplate()` method first:

```
MainContent.ApplyTemplate();
var x = (StackPanel)MainContent.Template.FindName("CUSTOMNAVBAR", MainContent);
```

Comment: @SebOlens you're welcome, if the answer is helpful, please accept it :), BTW looks like you're new to SO, to accept an answer, just click on the grayed tick mark right under the placeholder for votes number.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing elements in code behind you need to set x:Name directive. You seem  to use Name now. Preferably you should use databinding to get/set the values of WPF controls, like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label x:Name="PhotoFileName" Content="{Binding Imageinfo}">
```

(etc)

Comment: Nope, nothing changed when I added x:
Also, I don't want to get value I need access to this StackPanel I added so I can change it from code